# Post XML file content from client browser to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post

I want to get xml file content on the server by Ruby on Rails.
How can i do that without upload file. and send xml file content from client to server in user browser.
exactly what I want to do. writing an app to get gpx file content from a form. user should enter file path in the form and submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens when you upload a file in Rails, i.e. with a form like

```
<%= form_for @page, multipart: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

you get a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object in `params[:page][:name]`. This `UploadedFile` contains among others a `File` object called `tempfile`.

You can read and parse the content of the uploaded XML file from this `tempfile`

Normally you would use a gem like `paperclip` or `carrierwave` to handle file uploads.